# Extracting feature classes from file geodatabase to convert to CAD?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cad

I am trying to convert multiple feature classes located within a file geodatabase into a CAD friendly format.

Without extracting the files the "Export to CAD" tool does not recognize the feature class.

Comment: How would I extract the feature classes so that the "export to CAD" tool would recognize the layers?

Answer (score 1):

If you export your feature classes to shapefiles, you can then bring them directly into CAD. I support a dozen CAD users on a daily basis and 99% of the data I give them are ESRI shapefiles. Assuming your projections are correct, the shapefiles should drop exactly into place in CAD, and will retain their attribute data as well. I'll provide a link detailing the process to import the files with AutoCAD.

[AutoCAD Map 3D To Import SHP Files](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-map-3d/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/MAP3D-Use/files/GUID-D65473F6-0B63-4F4E-A3B7-9B8EE8217B77-htm.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by 'extract the feature class', you can export CAD data using the 'Export to CAD' tool in the conversion toolbox.  When using this tool, I can select feature classes from my geodatabase.

You can also use arcpy.ExportCAD_conversion if you know how to use python/arcpy.